# Can we have link previews before having to visit the links?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, hyperlinks

Consider this randomly chosen question opened in chrome, and later in the android app.

> [image: Link preview in chrome]

In Chrome, I can press and hold on any link to see the actual address before I even visit it. Whereas in the stack exchange android app, I'm not able to do so.

> [image: No link preview in android app]

This is **not** an important issue, but I'd simply love to have such a preview feature on our app.